# how to add caption to images in draft js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

Is is possible to render an input (for adding caption to images) inside the draft js and can get the data which is typed by user? I am familiar with "custom block rendering" concept and followed the instruction which is provided by https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-custom-block-render-map/  But, when I wanted to write something in the input, I faced the below error:

invariant.js:40 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Unknown DraftEntity key: null.

In fact, block?.getEntityAt(0) returns null, since character list changes when I started to type.

This is the custom block renderer code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { fromJS } from "immutable";

export const CustomBlockRenderer = (block, editorState, props) => {
  if (block.getType() === "atomic") {
    return {
      component: Media,
      editable: false,
    };
  }
  return null;
};

const Image = (props) => {
  if (!!props.src) {
    return <img src={props.src} />;
  }
  return null;
};

const Media = (props) => {
  const entity = props.contentState?.getEntity(props?.block?.getEntityAt(0));
  const { src } = entity?.getData();

  const type = entity?.getType();

  let customBlock;

  if (type === "image") {
    customBlock = (
      <figure className="custom-block__image-wrap">
        <Image src={src?.url} className="custom-block__image" />
        <figcaption className="custom-block__caption">{src?.caption}</figcaption>
      </figure>
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }

  return customBlock;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced with a similar issue recently. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-galileo-i6s3n?file=/index.js) the simplified demo of how it can work. Pay attention that `EditorBlock` component from `draft-js` is used on the image caption node. You should use `EditorBlock` in your custom component if you want an editable area inside the custom component.

```
class MyCustomBlock extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const imgSrc = this.props.block.get("data").src;

    return (
      <div className="my-custom-block">
        <figure className="custom-block__image-wrap">
          <img src={imgSrc} className="custom-block__image" />
          <figcaption className="custom-block__caption">
            <EditorBlock {...this.props} />
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]